# Python 2.7 - Converting a single character string to an integer

Tags: python, python-2.7, char, int, type-conversion

I'm trying to make a program which reads from two text file line by line and stores the line which you have specified in `Name_Input` earlier (in variable line and line 2), it then strips off anything which is not a number from the string.

```
for line in Roster_Inputed:  

        if Name_Input in line: 
            line = re.sub('[^0-20]', '', line)

            if line == "1":
                print(Name_Input + " " + "should have " + line + " " + "ally.")  
                print " "  
            else:
                print(Name_Input + " " + "should have " + line + " " + "allies.")
                print " " 

    for line2 in Roster_Should_Have:
        if Name_Input in line2:
            line2 = re.sub('[^0-20]', '', line2)

            if line2 == "1":
                print(Name_Input + " " + "actually has " + line2 + " " + "ally.") 
                print " "   
            else:
                print(Name_Input + " " + "actually has " + line2 + " " + "allies.")
                print " "
```

The code reads from two files which contain names and number after a space, it then goes on to compare them to determine what it outputs to the user:

```
     if line == line2:
        print "All good"
    elif line != line2:
        print "Check " + Name_Input + "'s " + "spies"
        print " "
```

What I need it to do is check if the value of "line" is greater than "line2" however I cannot do so because they are strings which contain numbers. Is there a way to temporarily convert them to integers?

Comment: That depends on what you mean by "greater".

Comment: If the value which is in the string is greater than the other (the actual number)

Comment: So, the characters are always digits?

Comment: The content of the variables "line" and "line 2" will always be digits, yes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`chr()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#chr) and [`ord()`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#ord) functions:

```
>>> chr(97)
'a'
>>> ord('a')
97
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

What about calling `int`?

```
>>> int('345')
345
```

Answer (score 0):

Since I have now gotten confirmation that the characters will always be integers and the integers are what you want to compare, I can now say use `int()`:

```
>>> int('4')
4
```

In your case, `if int(line) > int(line2):` should do what you want.  Since files usually have new-line characters at the end of each line, you should probably consider using `int(line.strip())` and `int(line2.strip())`.

Comment: Yes! Thank you very much.